# Menu navigation with Django

Tags: html, django

I have the view:

```
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {'page_about_exist':1,})
```

In html I have this code:

```
<li {% if page_about_exist %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="{% url about_project %}"> About</a></li>
```

So, If I go to the About-page, in menu it has class active, and I can see it visually. 
Is there any other way without the dictionary? Because I have in url

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login',),
```

and my way with dictionary doesnt look great there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this kind of thing with template inheritance. For example, your `base.html` might include a navigation list with:

```
<li{% block products %}{% endblock %}><a href...>Products</a></li>
<li{% block about %}{% endblock %}><a href...>About</a></li>
```

Then in your `about` template (assuming it inherits from `base`) you have:

```
{% block about %} class="active"{% endblock %}
```

This will render as pure html, using the class you have defined for active pages. Because it uses simple template inheritance you can also get really fine control with this.

Comment: @NickBewley Where is the repetition?

Comment: The difference is writing it once in `base.html` vs writing it multiple times in each template. Additionally, it makes more sense to keep all base elements (ie navigation) in `base.html`. Like I said, inheritance isnt wrong approach, but adds unnecessary elements to inherited templates, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I use my own template tag called `ifnav`.

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ifnav-templatetag
- https://bitbucket.org/bikeshedder/django-ifnav-templatetag

The usage is very simple. Just add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and make sure the request context processor is activated.

Afterwards you can write this:

```
<li {% ifnav "^/about/" %} class="active" {% endifnav %}><a href="{% url about_project %}"> About</a></li>
```

For current projects I use Django CMS which takes care of rendering the navigation.